# good Email services for Ecommerce site with .Net API?

Tags: c#, api, email

we are looking for service that can send bulk emails to registered customers on daily basis that has good and flexible c# API. the site will handle clients like a coupon site meaning daily mails and purchaces mails.

Comment: FYI, proper APIs are language agnostic

Answer (score 0):

We are using hMailServer and we access the service through ChilkatDotNet.